# What can Geralt do against "You look terrible" / "You look pale"?

Tags: the-witcher-3

When Geralt talks to people, they say randomly: "You look terrible!" or "You look pale!"

Are this hints that he should take a nap? Or eat something special?

*(I'm sure that Geralt is not poisened at this time.)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope. He just looks that way. Kinda like all the casual "freaks" and "mutants" that get tossed your way, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: In some laoding screen tips the game explains, that the most people dont like witchers because of their past. The cat school e.g. were well-known assassins so they killes more human than monsters